# Fantasy story of a girl, a black king and a white king, and a mirror

Tags: story-identification, books

I've read this book and cannot remember its name. It's fantasy obviously. There is a girl who gets approached or saved by a glittering creature who gives her a key on her tongue through a kiss (he ends up raping her along with 3 or 4 more). She also has a mentor; an old, not so pretty man.

There is a mirror that takes her to a castle with 2 kings; one black, one white. She remembered she's a queen, and was in love with one and needs to save the white king. At the end it turns out her mentor is the white king and the glittering creature was the black evil one.

It is a 2 or 3 books series.